# Inno Setup giving error "No files found matching" when including an empty folder to installation

Tags: python, installation, inno-setup

I have been trying to make an installer file with Inno Setup, but I am running into some error.

Following is the snippet of code where I encounter the error:

```
[Files]
Source: "E:\Programs\Kiara Project\Kiara Project\EXE\exe.win-amd64-3.8\Kiara.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "E:\Programs\Kiara Project\Kiara Project\EXE\exe.win-amd64-3.8\Intro_Images\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "E:\Programs\Kiara Project\Kiara Project\EXE\exe.win-amd64-3.8\lib\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "E:\Programs\Kiara Project\Kiara Project\EXE\exe.win-amd64-3.8\Notes\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "E:\Programs\Kiara Project\Kiara Project\EXE\exe.win-amd64-3.8\Screens\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "E:\Programs\Kiara Project\Kiara Project\EXE\exe.win-amd64-3.8\Screenshots\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "E:\Programs\Kiara Project\Kiara Project\EXE\exe.win-amd64-3.8\System_Files\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "E:\Programs\Kiara Project\Kiara Project\EXE\exe.win-amd64-3.8\python38.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

I am getting this error:

> No files found matching "E:\Programs\Kiara Project\Kiara Project\EXE\exe.win-amd64-3.8\Notes*"

[image]

If it helps, `Notes` is an empty folder which I have to include.
Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (ab)use `[Files]` section entry to create an empty directory. The `[Files]` section is for files, not folders.

Use [`[Dirs]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection) to create a folder.

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\Notes"
```

---

Additionally, if you want to install files into a subfolder, you have to make that subfolder the destination path:

```
[Files]
Source: "E:\Programs\Kiara Project\Kiara Project\EXE\exe.win-amd64-3.8\Intro_Images\*"; \
    DestDir: "{app}\Intro_Images"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

---

Alternatively, include whole root folder of your project and use [`Excludes` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=Excludes) to exclude the files you do not won't to include.

```
[Files]
Source: "E:\Programs\Kiara Project\Kiara Project\EXE\exe.win-amd64-3.8\*"; \
    DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; \
    Excludes: "do_not_include_this\*"
```

Though this might be a fragile approach.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate the quick response!!